# Reboot and select proper boot device?

Tags: windows-10, boot, operating-systems

So i was working on a project in Indesign when I suddenly encountered some problem with some graphics in indesign. After a few seconds, the computer got a message ( The Blue Screen of Death ) where the stop code was: System Service Exception.

[image: Blue Screen Of Death: Stop Code System_Service_Exception]

The computer was supposed to restart but instead it did not restart and got a black screen message which read `Reboot and select proper boot device`.

[image: black screen]

I looked up the internet and saw many others facing the same problem as well. However their problem were solved by changing the boot options or loading default settings.

I tried changing all booting options.

There were two booting options:

> Boot Option No 1: SATA Firm s11
>
> Boot Option No 2: St200dm006.

I tried both but still the computer could not be booted. I am guessing SATA firm s11 is my ssd and st200 is my HDD. My operating system was installed in the SSD.

Can you tell me whether my files in the local disk D and E would be affected or not? Since I have a lot of important career files in the Hard Disk drive

Comment: It could be a very scrambled operating system or a hardware issue on the disk.  Get the Manufacturer's Test Application and put on a bootable USB Key. Start with that and test the hardware.

Comment: Likely an issue with the HDD the OS is installed to, else it would have booted WinRE if it couldn't load the OS.  Run a S.M.A.R.T test - the easiest way is to create an Ubuntu install USB → boot it → choose Try Ubuntu → Open a terminal via `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T` → `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install smartmontools` → `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda ; sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda ; sleep 61 ; sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` → Open 2nd terminal: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb ; sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdb ; sleep 61 ; sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb`. Please post the results of both for final `smartctl -a`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select your boot device default in the BIOS settings. If changing that doesn't work, you could load a separate OS onto a USB or disk and put it in and boot from that. It could be that your copy of Windows is corrupted now. There are several Softwares out there that can fix that, but be careful, as a lot of them are scams.

Hopefully, if you manage to boot to another OS on a USB, if it has a file explorer, you'll be able to look through the files on the SSD with Windows on it, and you can check if any files are missing. (Though that would take a while)

Hopefully, if it's just a scrambled operating system, your files should be fine. As `John` said in a comment, it could also be a hardware issue with the disk.

Hope this helps!